# Convert object array to string array including null values

Tags: c#, lambda, arrays

I want to convert object array into string array without excluding null values..
I got the following code to convert object array to string array.But it excludes null values..

```
string[] foo = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

I searched a lot in Google,but failed to find a solution

Pls help.

EDIT:-
Got the answer...

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(); 
foreach (object o in myvalues) 
if (o==null)
 { 
lst.Add(null); 
} 
else 
{ 
lst.Add(o.ToString()); 
} 
string[] str2 = lst.ToArray();
```

Comment: This question is not related to Asp .Net MVC3. Tag removed as non constructive.

Answer (score 2):

You filter out the null values with the OfType call. You can try something like

```
string[] fo = myvalues.Select(o => o == null ? (string)null : o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can use below approach for converting **Object Array** to **String
>   Array**.

```
Object[] ObjArray= Dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;        

string[] StrArray= Array.ConvertAll(ObjArray,Convert.ToString);
```

(for null object value in object array, it will keep empty string in string array.)